# Phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner doesn't work on ios 13

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Everything is ok on ios 12. But on ios 13, i start to scan, my app is terminated with error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'App called -statusBar or -statusBarWindow on UIApplication: this code must be changed as there's no longer a status bar or status bar window. Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead.'
```

I'm using Cordova version: 8.1.2, phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner: 7.1.0

Do guys have any suggestions?